# Following https://meet.google.com/new redirects with cURL

Tags: http, curl, redirect, http-redirect, google-meet

Google Meet currently doesn't have an API to get a meeting link programmatically, unfortunately. The only way as of today is to use the Calendar API which requires oAuth.

That being said we can use the /new endpoint to directly start a meeting through a browser.

Would it be possible to do the same with curl?

Here is what I was trying -

```sh
curl -H 
  'user-agent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36"' \
  https://meet.google.com/new \
  -L -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} -s
```

Basically trying to follow the redirects, but it doesn't seem to be working. I definitely am missing something.

I've also tried with cookies - `-b cookie -c cookie` - to no avail.

What is the difference between the curl http client and the browser that I need to fill in, in order for this concept to work?

Any help would be highly appreciated.
TIA.